# XSLT from the web - Needing the right dev/test environment

Tags: html, xslt, development-environment

Mostly for learning and testing-purposes, I need an environment/software where I can apply XSL Transformations on websites (html).
It needs to support Sessions and Cookies because of a login required to actually reach the pages I want to transform via XSL.

The manual method aka calling the page in the browser and download it and copy into Eclipse for example, is too slow. I need an automated system.. if possible one which can call multiple pages via a script.

I know that this could be realized with a lot of coding in Java, but I hoped for a simpler solution...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue why people have downed this question -_-', but I've found a sufficing solution:
Using "wget" for downloading the files and Saxon HE (NET) for actually applying the transformations. Those programs can be easily called from windows CMD :)